# css design for a print preview of a page or documents

Tags: html, css, printing

In my program, user creates a html document, which will be converted to either pdf or printed directly.

I want to preview it exactly how it will be printed to give user some idea and allow them to modify some part if it needs to be.

Is there any css framework which can help me here ?

And if I create my own stylesheet, whats ideal measurement should I use ? pixel or em or pt or  ?

Comment: Is the document more than one page?

Comment: yes. it could be of multiple page. i am using paged css media, but it does not show up in browser.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no CSS framework for such a thing but here are a couple good articles that could help you out... [GoToPrint](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/), [Create a simple print CSS](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/)... also you want to stick to pt's as these are used in printing. px and em are for screen.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [PrintCSS](http://www.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/themes/onextrapixel/print.css) in this case.

[Print CSS](http://www.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/themes/onextrapixel/print.css) is a Cascading Style Sheet intended for print documents when users want to print the web page for reference. It applies to document view in print preview mode as well, therefore you can preview how the print document looks like after you have made amendment on your Print CSS.

Answer (score 1):

hartija is a css print framework: http://code.google.com/p/hartija/

Answer (score 0):

There is Gutenberg, a modern framework to print correctly (https://github.com/BafS/Gutenberg).

(Disclosure: I am the author)